# Set outline first and fill colors later

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}       
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10,   
             ticks=none}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, 
                calc,
                patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4, transform shape]
\tikzset{
    myc/.pic={
    \draw[line width=2mm] (0, 0) -| (2, 1) -| (1, 2) -| (2, 3) -| cycle;
        }
}
\path (0,0) pic[fill=green] {myc} (1,3) pic[fill=blue] {myc} (2,6) pic[fill=blue] {myc};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The code defines the outline of a tile in the line starting with `tikzset{`

I want to put this tile at various places and I want to use different colors to fill the tile. The above code is one of the attempts to get this done, which however does not work.

The output I get is the following:

[image]

I very recently learnt about the `tikzset` command (thanks to TeXstackexchange) and have no understanding of it. Can somebody please help me here and also, if possible, suggest a reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `pic actions`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4, transform shape]
\tikzset{
    myc/.pic={
    \draw[line width=2mm,pic actions] (0, 0) -| (2, 1) -| (1, 2) -| (2, 3) -| cycle;
        }
}
\path (0,0) pic[fill=green] {myc} (1,3) pic[fill=blue] {myc} (2,6) pic[fill=blue] {myc};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @caffeinemachine I personally prefer `pic actions` over an argument in the pic in this case because you can then add `dashed` and/or `draw=red` and so on which you cannot do in the same simple way if you use arguments of the `pic`s.

Answer (score 4):

Your `pic` can have arguments.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}       
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10,   
             ticks=none}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, 
                calc,
                patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4, transform shape]
\tikzset{
    myc/.pic={
    \draw[line width=2mm,fill=#1] (0, 0) -| (2, 1) -| (1, 2) -| (2, 3) -| cycle;
        }
}
\path (0,0) pic {myc=red} (1,3) pic {myc=green} (2,6) pic {myc=blue};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah I looked at the manual. But it's big. Can you tell me under what heading should I look? Thanks.

Comment: @caffeinemachine Alright, it is in section 18, especially 18.3. It tells you how to define new `pic`s. Reading about the key handler and the example on page 264, you will know that `pic` is, literally, a kind of style. So you read about `.style` key handler in section 87.4.4, page 966, and boom, you know how to add one, or two, or even nine arguments to a `pic`.